# Tap twice to make WindowSoftInputMode work

Tags: android, android-fragments, window-soft-input-mode

I have a simple form with EditText fields and one button at the end, and each edittext is wrapped with a TextInputLayout. I have implemented in my AndroidManifest the WindowSoftInputMode="adjustPan", but when I build the app the first time I tap on an editText it does not work, then I tap again on the same editText and it works, then I type again and it does not work, etc...

The form is a fragment, and the fragment is inside a DrawerLayout, I have no idea what is wrong, and I just don't paste the code because is giant and I am sure it is unreadeable. I just want to know if anyone has had an issue like this one.

PS: I tried AdjustResize and others, but it get worst, the layout that contains the form resizes to the half of the screen.